# Why should the base $f(x)$ of a function of the form $h(x)=(f(x))^{g(x)}$ should always be positive for $h(x)$ to be defined?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why should the base $f(x)$ of a function of the form $h(x)=(f(x))^{g(x)}$ should always be positive for $h(x)$ to be defined ?

Comment: Because $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$, so you must be able to calculate $\ln a$, which means $a>0$.

Comment: But I define $h(x)=(-x^2)^x$, then it is clearly defined at $x=2$, i.e. $(-4)^{2}=16$. Can you explain why ? @NicolasFRANCOIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't, if $g(x)$ happens to always be an integer or a rational with odd denominator.  But if you want real numbers, you can't have $f^g$ where $f < 0$ and $g$ is irrational or a rational with even denominator (in lowest terms).